# Where can I find a description of the SHA-0 hash algorithm?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, implementation, reference-request, history

Where can I find the description and or pseudocode for the SHA-0 hash algorithm? I am looking for something on these lines: [HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) [RIPEMD](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ebosselae/ripemd/rmd128.txt).

I have been implementing a few of those ([HMAC, HOTP, TOTP](https://github.com/lordloh/OPT_algorithms) and [MD4, MD5, RIPEMD-128,160](https://github.com/lordloh/cryptoy))

Comment: Is there a specific reason beyond historical relevance as to why you want to implement the 20-year-long broken predecessor of the broken SHA-1 which also only sees minimal usage?

Comment: Also [the original attack paper (PDF)](http://fchabaud.free.fr/English/Publications/sha.pdf) on SHA-0 contains a description which credits the specification to FIPS 180 (which I couldn't easily find).

Comment: @SEJPM - Do you mean this -  https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/180/archive/1993-05-11 I am just implementing them for fun. I have already implemented MD4, MD5, RIPEMD-128,160. I wish I had done this years ago. It has granted me some insight into the hashing algorithms and a lot more questions to ponder on.

Comment: Yes I meant the document associated to that page, however it isn't provided there :(

Comment: I have put a request with my University library for the FIPS-180 (1993). Lets see if their document delivery department delivers :-D. In the past they gave up on my requests for test image sets that were used in Jpeg 2000.

Comment: My university library's document delivery failed to deliver. They sent me this message - 

`has been cancelled by the interlibrary loan staff for the following reason: 
***We are unable to find a library willing to lend us this item. ***
No library is able to supply this item.`

Comment: You can ask them for the document on ANS X9.23 (padding) as well in case you want to annoy them further :P Seriously though, NIST should be able to supply this, but note that e.g. X9.23 was *only made available in paper format*!

Comment: ha ha ha ha! I must take care not to be blacklisted :-D I may need some serious document for my research!

Comment: More on topic, the [page of IAIK Graz on SHA-0 Cryptanalysis](https://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/SHA-0) contains a list of papers on the subject, of which at least "Collisions on SHA-0 in One Hour", "Near-Collisions of SHA-0" and "Differential Collisions in SHA-0" are publicly available and contain a description of the algorithm. That's second hand, but with the number of references to these papers they should be considered very reliable. They are all available, although the org. paper of Joux et all is a scanned PDF...

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep an eye on the NIST link. I have been searching github hoping that someone put it in their repository, but had no luck so far.

Comment: @Lord Loh: there is free JPEG 2000 Conformance testing material [here](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_IEC_15444-4_2004_Conformance_Testing/ISO_IEC_15444-4_2004_Conformance_Testing.zip). It is not from the first version of the standard, though.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the docs. https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/algorithmic-space/cryptoy/blob/master/SHA1.ipynb - here is the implementation that I came up with based on these docs. SHA0 + one left shift = SHA1 :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reference on SHA(-0) is [FIPS 180 (archived scan)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180905102133/https://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Pierre.Karpman/fips180.pdf) of 1993 May 11. The standard itself is referenced on the [NIST website](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/180/archive/1993-05-11), but that links to another scan lacking page 1 and the one before, thus foreword, abstract, explanation... There's also this [text draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20180905103451/http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/gwydion/external-sources/distributed-computing/ilu/stubbers/parser/SHSDoc) of 1992 January 22 (also [here](https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt/blob/master/SDeanComponents/Components/Hash/docs/SHA/fips_sha_shs.standard) with less indication on origin).

---

The Proposal for Change of that into SHA-1 was published on 1994 July 11 and is [online at the Federal Register](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/1994/07/11/94-16666/proposed-revision-of-federal-information-processing-standard-fips-180-secure-hash-standard) with [partially garbled text](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/FR-1994-07-11/html/94-16666.htm), including for the security-critical change:

> In Section 7 of [1] (page 9), the line which reads
>     (b) For t=16 to 79 let W<sub>t</sub> = W<sub>t-3</sub> XOR W<sub>t-8</sub> XOR W<sub>t-14</sub> XOR W<sub>t-16</sub>.
> is to be replaced by
>     (b) For t=16 to 79 let W<sub>t</sub> = S<sup>1</sup>(W<sub>t-3</sub> XOR W<sub>t-8</sub> XOR W<sub>t-14</sub> XOR W<sub>t-16</sub>).
> where S<sup>1</sup> is a left circular shift by one bit as defined in Section
> 3 of [1] (page 6), namely S<sup>1</sup>(X) = (X << 1) v (X >> 31).

<sup>Note: What's kept of the original PfC has messed-up sub/superscripts (a modern web artifact), and misses the closing parenthesis on the modified expression for W<sub>t</sub> (possibly an omission in the original).</sup>
This is was a technical change in the design, critical for improved security, rather than a correction of a typographical error as could be understood by casual reading of the PfC. This change was introduced without rationale, and initially without ensuing changes in the test vectors. It is thus reasonable to suspect that it was intentionally sneaked quietly, with knowledge that the original was not as secure as intended against educated collision attacks.

The revised document is [FIPS 180-1](https://web.archive.org/web/20000816062527/http://csrc.nist.gov/fips/fip180-1.pdf) of 1995 April 17, referenced on the [NIST website](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/180/1/archive/1995-04-17) (with a link to an external [scan](https://ia800100.us.archive.org/14/items/federalinformati1801nati/federalinformati1801nati.pdf) of the actual document).

---

Changing source code for SHA-1 into one for SHA(-0) is easy: just remove the one-bit rotations of a 32-bit word of the 512-bit message block. For example, in the reference implementation of [RFC 6234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6234#page-36), change

```
W[t] = SHA1_ROTL(1, W[t-3] ^ W[t-8] ^ W[t-14] ^ W[t-16]);
```

to

```
W[t] =          (   W[t-3] ^ W[t-8] ^ W[t-14] ^ W[t-16]);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I should have thought of the way back machine!

Comment: @Lord Loh: AFAIK the Wayback Machine has no good search engine, and did not contain the FIPS 180 scan before my answer. I stepped on that scan in 2016, and kept the URL. The website has vanished, but the researcher kept the same organization on his new website, which allowed to find a working URL, allowing the Wayback Machine to archive. For FIPS 180-1, I had a native PDF dated 1997. At that time I used a MacOS 9 browser keeping URLs as "finder comments", kept in my archives as NTFS streams emulated by Samba on an ext4 RAID6 volume on a NAS, and the Wayback Machine had that document archived.

Comment: Wow! I should upvote your answer more than once!

Comment: @LordLoh. Be sure to download the PDF yourself. If the website ever goes down and a new owner puts up an exclusionary robots.txt, the Wayback Machine will censor the website's archive.

Comment: https://github.com/algorithmic-space/cryptoy/tree/master/specs - I have mirrored the pdf in my github repository :-)

Comment: RFC 6491 might also be of interest, if only for the normative references.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a copy [directly from NIST at the DOI site](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180).

And yes, I simply asked and got multiple, very polite responses. Thanks NIST!

Comment: The scan linked in this answer is missing two printed pages (page 1 and the one before), including foreword, abstract, explanation... that are in the one linked in [my answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62071/555). On the other hand, we get the scan of the jacket, complete with "Penalty for private use $300" on the back. I guess they originate from the same paper copy since holes appear to be at the same position.

Comment: Weird that it misses the pages. Hmmm.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this - https://github.com/tyage/sha0/blob/master/lib/sha0.rb I don't know how good or accurate it is.

Comment: I had come across this in my search. But was looking for more like an RFC / pseudocode from the original specification.